# Install a component again during repair by WIX installer

Tags: wix

I want to write on a registry when i install my product. I could've successfully done that inside a component.

```
<Component Win64='$(var.Win64)' Id='RegistrySetup' Guid='840D9DC3-3F98-4597-A089-D649EC3E7FEB' Directory='TARGETDIR'>

      <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key='[UtillRegKey]' ForceCreateOnInstall='yes' ForceDeleteOnUninstall='yes' >
        <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
      </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

`[UtillRegKey]` is generated by a custom action, so the value is differ for each time it runs.

Now I need to run this installer as change mode, And do some works. 
When I run on change mode i need to run above compnent again to make another registry key.

Is there any way to do that?

**Edit:**

What i meant "run on change mode" is, if the installer runs for second time "MaintenanceTypeDlg" will be opened. and it has three buttons "Change", "Repair" & "remove". (I am customizing `WixUI_Mondo` )

I Changed this dialog to use this change button to do what i intended to do. (instead of add/remove features i want to write on the registry once more)

If "Change" button clicked `WixUI_InstallMode` property will be set as "Change"

```
 <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="Change">1</Publish>
```

I tried to use custom action but since the user doesn't have the write permission to the registry key, i could not do it either.

Comment: Can you add the custom action definition and where it is scheduled? That would be the  `<CustomAction>` tag and `<Custom>` tag inside one of the Execute Sequence tags.

Comment: Also you might want to run your msi with logging enabled to see what it is doing. I'm not sure what the command line args for a repair/change install are but you should be able to find them with a bit of searching.

Comment: What does "run this installer as change mode" mean? I've not heard that before. The choices are patch, major upgrade, repair, minor upgrade. Are you attempting to use repair to change the registry item, or are you installing a new version of the product?

Comment: @PhilDW I updated the question. Sorry for misleading and my poor knowledge. do you now have an idea what i want to say?